# "Expanding" foreign keys in my json views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models, `Product`, `Order` and `OrderItem`. Given an instance of `Order`, you can get a list of order items by calling `order.order_items`. Each `OrderItem` must have exactly one `Product` object, which is referenced by a `product_id`.

I want to create a RESTful API where clients can ask for information about an order and my server will "join" all of the data at once. As opposed to having the client use javascript to iterate each order item, taking the product ID, and making a request to the `product.json` view which will return the information for requested product.

I have such a `product.json` view, but I *think* it would be better to make it easier to use my API as well as minimize the number of requests made to the server (I have no argument to support this belief, however)

For example, the output I would like to return when you ask for information about order 1 would look like

```
{ "order_id" : 1,
  "order_items" : [
    {
      "order_item_id" : 1,
      "product" : {
        "name": "Carrots"
      }
    },
    {
      "order_item_id" : 2,
      "product" : {
        "name": "Tuna"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have started with this in my `order.json` view

```
json.(@order, :order_items)
```

And it shows this

```
{ "order_id" : 1,
  "order_items" : [
    {
      "order_item_id" : 1,
      "product_id" : 13
    },
    {
      "order_item_id" : 2,
      "product_id" : 128
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is pretty close, but what can I add to expand the `product_id` inside each order item and replace them with the fields of the product.

How can I achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try using the :include option of the to_json method as the follow

```
order = Order.find(1)
order.to_json( include: { order_items: { include: {:product} } } )
```

I hope it helps :)